# Azure DevOps REST API - Get Task Group Parameter Details

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a collection of Azure DevOps pipeline jobs that consume a number of shared Task Groups, but in addition, each also has its own discrete set of pipeline Tasks and other configuration settings.

Is there an Azure DevOps REST API command that I can run to generate for each Pipeline, the list of pipeline tasks (including those of the consumed Task Groups) and their configuration settings, including parameters?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an Azure DevOps REST API command that I can run to generate for each Pipeline, the list of pipeline tasks (including those of the consumed Task Groups) and their configuration settings, including parameters?

The answer is yes.

You could use the Azure DevOps REST API command [az pipelines build definition show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines/build/definition?view=azure-cli-latest#az-pipelines-build-definition-show):

```
az pipelines build definition show [--detect {false, true}]
                                   [--id]
                                   [--name]
                                   [--open]
                                   [--org]
                                   [--project]
                                   [--subscription]
```

Its return is a Json formatted content, like:

[image]

If you want to automatically list all the pipeline information, then you can consider using the REST API:

[Definitions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

Comment: That's great @Leo Liu-MSFT. Will give it a go and provide some feedback.